# how to change font color of tooltip text

Tags: html, fonts, tooltip

I have a piece of code that has a word in a table, I also have a tool tip attached to the word, however, the tooltip function changes the color of my word blue. How can I keep the word the same color as the other words in the table?

Here is my code.

```
<th><strong><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Please press the name of the drug you want to review" font color = "black">Name</strong></th>
```

Comment: AFAIK the traditional "tooltip" (so title) color cannot be styled. It is created by the browser, hard wired. You could think of using a tooltip library that replaces the traditional tooltip with code that offers much more features and also allows custom styling.

Comment: if this is HTML5, don't use `<a>` unless you're linking to a real URL (`href="#"` is an HTML3.2 hack, and under HTML4 an HTML5 means "navigate to the top of the page"). If you need a button, use a `<button>`, because CSS makes "but I want it to look like text" irrelevant. `border:none`, `background: inherit`, done. It is now text.